# Rich Text Editor control with edit option for WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, rich-text-editor, outlook-2013

I want to have a RichTextEditor control which will have all the editing option like BOLD, ITALIC, STYLE, FONT...
I want to use it in a winform where the content of the editor will be an Outlook mail body (Outlook 2013) i.e it should support all rich text,image etc.

In VS 2012 we don't have any control of this type !!!

Answer (score 2):

`RichTextBox` does have these options. Just paste a formatted text into it to see it.

Of course, there is no `OutlookNewMessageWithFormattingControlsForm`, you have to implement the functionality behind your BOLD, ITALIC, etc. buttons/menu items.

See the example below. `btnBold` is a `CheckBox` with `Appearance.Button`, `menuItemBold` is a `ToolStripMenuItem`.

```
private bool isAdjusting;

private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox1.SelectionFont == null)
        return;

    bool isBold = (richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style & FontStyle.Bold) == FontStyle.Bold;
    isAdjusting = true;
    btnBold.Checked = isBold;
    menuItemBold.Checked = isBold;
    isAdjusting = false;
}

private void btnBold_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isAdjusting)
        return;
    SetBold(btnBold.Checked);
}

private void SetBold(bool bold)
{
    if (richTextBox1.SelectionFont == null)
        return;

    FontStyle style = richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style;
    style = bold ? style | FontStyle.Bold : style & ~FontStyle.Bold;
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, style);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What i am asking is when mail body is copied to the control body, END USER should be able or have the option to do all the styling like bold, italic,font...like we have in MS-WORD !!!

Comment: As I have said, you should implement this functionality. See my edited answer. You can also assign hotkeys for menu items, such as `Ctrl+B`.

Comment: @DigambarMalla
or (if this is a project you are starting now) you could move to WPF which has rich text editor nuget packages that do exactly what you need

Comment: The net is full of complete examples for WinForms as well. It doesn't make any sense to switch to WPF just to use another 3rd party solution. See TX Text Control or TE Edit, or FireFX Editor, all of these are WinForms-based professional editors. Or, here is a complete example for the do-it-yourself version: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18356/Word-Processor-Based-Upon-an-Extended-RichTextBox It doesn't matter whether WPF or WinForms, you cannot avoid some implementation with the base .NET components.